# RactiveJS and Stapes model not updating

Tags: javascript, ractivejs, stapes.js

I am trying to create a filtering for a Stapes object in RactiveJS, but it seem the two way binding is not responding correctly to the update.

I can't work out what is going wrong where as I thought it should just work without any issue, I have created a code example here:

https://jsbin.com/sajeje/4/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pattern I use for using a computed property with a filter adapted for your use case. I couldn't get the Stapes object to directly be usable as the result, but there is a `getAllAsArray()` that seems to work:

```
  computed: {
    filtered: function () {
       var query = this.get( 'query').trim(),
           users = this.get( 'users' );

      return query ? users.search(query) : users.getAllAsArray();
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      users: usersModel,
      query: ''
    }
  }
```

Works with the sub-component as pure reactive programming without the need for an event:

```
<Search query="{{query}}" placeholder="Search users" />
```

**Updated** bin here: https://jsbin.com/bomumajagu/edit?html,output

Push works against Stapes model:

```
this.get( 'users' ).push( { name: newUser } );
```

Comment: That explains it a bit, but now I am left without two way binding to the model usersModel.push(), as we are binding to the array instead and since the array is now a computed property I cant do allUsers.push() either.

Comment: Do note I was using the Stapes Adapter in order to pass through the usersModel in the data. https://github.com/dwightjack/ractive-adaptors-stapes

Comment: Right. So this solves the query data event issue, have updated to allow push into Stapes Model. Sorry not too familiar with that library or its adaptor

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I will have to read through the code to make sure I understand it all, but its definitely a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your users array. Your filtered result is derived from your search query and the users array. Use computed properties for this. Essentially, the search result is *another* array.

Here's an example using POJO, not Stapes, but same idea: http://jsfiddle.net/561fj33a/

HTML:

```
<script type="template/ractive" id="template-users-list">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="{{ query }}">
    </div>
    <ul>
        {{# usersList }}
        <li>{{ name }}</li>
        {{/}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var UsersList = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#template-users-list',
    data: {
        query: '',
        users: []
    },
    computed: {
        usersList: function () {
            var query = this.get('query');
            var users = this.get('users');
            return !query ? users : users.filter(function (user) {
                return ~user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query);
            });
        }
    }
});

var usersList = new UsersList({
    el: 'body',
    append: true
});

setTimeout(function () {
    usersList.set('users', [{
        name: 'James'
    }, {
        name: 'John'
    }, {
        name: 'Jenny'
    }, {
        name: 'George'
    }, {
        name: 'Harry'
    }]);
}, 2000);
```